# Of all things... (in-depth and NTFS-related)

Tags: windows-7, windows, ntfs

I was using 7-Zip and found some files that I was wanting to take a look at the hex dump of (out of curiosity) prefixed by a dollar sign. I used it to copy the files to a directory that I knew that they wouldn't exist nor be used. Now I've run into a dilemma: I want to either delete them or rename them. I know that *this* issue is most likely unresolvable through Windows, but in case this would fare better, I have had an Ubuntu installation for a while. I would prefer to do it through Windows, but it would entail some sort of direct BIOS call to the hard drive or something to that effect. I would like to rename it to something not involving dollar signs (It is one of *those*--and that's the same reason why this is a whole lot more difficult than a simple protected Windows file).

I have looked other places here to see if I can delete it, but that's easier said than done considering that the dollar sign is something that I'm pretty sure would not be easy to find using Linux. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

As a side note, at least I know the file isn't in a spot where it would cause problems.

Comment: so are you saying you have found some ntfs metadata files, and are wondering how to keep NTFS from treating them as such, and hiding them from the file system API?

Comment: or are you talking about a rootkit?

Comment: No, and no. I was wanting to look at them in more or less their hex code out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand what problem you would have in windows with such a file.
I proceeded to make not only files with the $sign, but also folders using the doller sign, and promply deleted both at will.
I can also create a pagefile.sys file on some disk that does not have it, that is not designated in the registry, it is just a file?

If your a full admin in windows you can even Shift-Delete the whole $RECYCLE.BIN if you are so inclined.

Is there more to this $file that I am not testing?

In a windows system to find out the charachters they really don't like you putting into things, try to rename, or make a new file and use that |  or the slashes or a ?, it will throw up all the things you should not use.

Comment: When I started reading this post, I realized that I needed to check the "Show protected operating system files" box in the settings in Explorer. After I did that, I am now able to do what I was wanting to do in the first place.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as an answer to close the thread. (don't have a lot in reputation).